# find 3rd max of salary in a large scale sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

one of my job interview questions was this.
I answered with order by and he ask me even in trillion rows?
I accepted my mistake and say I guess there is an option for MAX() maybe!!

in these questions:

[Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

[SQL select nth member of group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463054/sql-select-nth-member-of-group)

the trillion rows not considered and performance is low.

but after many search I found that even answered questions are not right for large scale rows.
anybody know what is the correct query?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are different DBMS, which one do you use and What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, if you could make the salary an indexed column, then it would be  faster.

Comment: mysql @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: This question is NOT about how to express a query to get the top n.  The OP clearly knows how to do that.  It is how to address the question of what to do about a trillion rows.

Comment: and you say index in every column ?

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` is fine.  You just want an index on the column.

If I had a table with a trillion rows and one of the columns was called `salary`, I would question the data model or implementation.  In any case, it would be in a highly parallel database.  Such databases tend to have their quirks, but there are usually methods to extract the value.

Of course, what the interviewer was looking for is more like:

```
select max(t.col)
from t
where t.column < (select max(t2.col)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col < (select max(t3.col) from t)
                 );
```

This would scan the table three times and has no intermediate steps for aggregation or sorting.  But in practice, there are likely to be other solutions depending on the database.

Comment: too long time for trillion rows

Comment: @HamidShariati . . . I'm not sure what that comment is supposed to mean.  Using an index is going to be quite fast.  And the subquery requires scanning the table three times, which is much faster than actually sorting the data.

Comment: but who whould use index for salary?

Comment: @HamidShariati . . . Someone who wanted to find the third largest value.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical use case for window functions (if supported by the concerned RDBMS), so something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x 
WHERE rn = 3
```

This query would take advantage of an index on column `Salary`.

Bottom line : there is no way that you can get that result without scanning the whole table and ordering (or aggregating) the results. Indexing is the key to optimize that.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the issue with a trillion rows.  It would still be doing a sort.

Comment: Yes, any solution would require scanning + sorting or aggregating.

Answer (score 0):

**In Mysql:-**

```
  SELECT *
       FROM tblSalary t1
       WHERE ( n) = 
       ( 
       SELECT COUNT( t2.columnSalary )
       FROM tblSalary t2
       WHERE t2.columnSalary >= t1.columnSalary
       )
```

**where (n) you can put any number to return highest salary..**

Comment: my server hanged in my session :-(. too long time query for trillion rows

Answer (score 0):

according to the mysql documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-info.html

I think partitioning is the best way for huge data