# Query to find second highest value per group

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Write a query to extract the department and second highest salary in each department

Employee

```
| Column         | Value          |
| -------------- | -------------- |
| employee_id    | int            |
| name           | string         |
| department     | string         |
| employment_type| string         |
| salary         | int            |
```

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63fGa.png)

Comment: What'S your question? Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far by yourself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL select nth member of group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463054/sql-select-nth-member-of-group)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

```
SELECT department, MAX(salary) AS second_high FROM Employee
WHERE second_high < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee)
GROUP BY department
```

Comment: please add explanation, so the SP can understand

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select e.department,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then e.salary end) as second_highest
from (select e.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e
group by e.department;
```

You can read the documentation on what `dense_rank()` does.  In this case, it assigns "1" to the rows with the highest salary, "2" to the rows with the second highest, and so on.